# "Live Demo" image switch via upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to build a "demo" website for a client who wishes to show the template to their customers.  One feature they are really looking for is to allow the user to upload their logo (jpg, png) and have that replace the placeholder logo image in real-time.  It should also only be temporary until the site is refreshed.

The sample site is going to be be only the homepage, and its a complete PHP/HTML site with no database.

Is this possible?  I've spent the better part of the morning looking over Google and haven't really found anything.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I've got it figured out, at least the basic concept of what I'm looking for.

So I used the ajaxupload.js from [Valums](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) for the uploader, then included the My Image Scale jQuery from Hermits to auto scale the image to the containing div.

I currently have the image being loaded into a li that the script creates, and then being moved using .replaceWith to replace the original logo.  This works perfectly.

Now I am going to adjust the code to not require the creation of the li element before moving.

For anyone else looking to do this, here's a [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/zqfBmP9H)

Thanks to everyone for all your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If it's one page only, you can save the page's output as HTML with all javascript/css/images statically linked.

You could then define a region inside the HTML which can can be replaced (e.g. with HTML comments `<!-- edit:start -->...<!-- edit:end -->` or CSS comments `/* edit:start */.../* edit:end */`) that can be dynamically changed, for example with the temporary image (-URL).

But your question is quite broad and there can be numerous ways on how to do that, so this is just one idea or probably only one aspect of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could allow the user to upload an image, then after the image is uploaded, load it into a `$_SESSION` variable. When outputting the logo image, check for the existence of the `$_SESSION` variable you created on upload and if it exists, change the source of the logo to an output script that reads the `$_SESSION` variable and outputs its contents with the proper headers.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_FILES['logo_upload'])) {
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['logo_upload']['tmp_name'], "r");
    $cntnts = fread($handle, filesize($_FILES['logo_upload']['tmp_name']));
              fclose($handle);
    $_SESSION['logo_data'] = $cntnts;
}
?>
```

Comment: I understand the concept here, but am wondering about the timing of it.  I mean, the page would have already loaded/rendered, before the user uploads an image.  I suppose I could try to do some sort of "onUpload" sorta thing to swap the image after the user completes the upload.  Or is that what you are already say?

Comment: That seems like a good approach. After using an ajax upload call you could check the callback data and if it was successful then you can change the source of the logo to the PHP script that outputs the user's uploaded logo. This could also be accomplished without ajax by setting the upload form's target to a hidden iframe and having the PHP script loaded inside the iframe output some JavaScript that changes the source of the logo image on successful upload.